What is the purpose of the "REF" pin of LTC6915?
I am working with a LTC6915 and i don't understand what REF pin does.
That like V+ - V- + Vref = Vout?
Or something else? I don't understand the datasheet.

so where's that schematic then showing the actual voltage on all pins? You have two answers now that cannot answer your further debugging question without that information.

where input is (V(in+) - V(in-))
Vout = gain*input + Vref
or to put it another way
(Vout-Vref) = gain * input
or to express it yet another way
differential output (Vout-Vref) = gain * differential input (V(in+) - V(in-))

Okay, but when i put 500mV in REF and V+ - V- = 500mV, i got 500mV as Vout

What gain setting do you have (is the amp saturating?(or any of its internal nodes?)), what power supply voltages (are they enough?), and what are the absolute V+ and V- voltages (have you respected any common mode requirements?) as well as their difference. A schematic in your question might help as well, to show what you're measuring voltages with respect to.

These equations hold if the Ref pin is driven with zero impedance.

@tobalt surely if the Ref pin has a voltage Vref, then it has a voltage Vref, regardless of how it's being driven? The circuitry internal to the IC senses the voltage on the Vref pin. Usually it will be connected to a low impedance like GND.

Yes you are right. This comment was angled more towards an incorrect perception of what Vref might be. I.e. if you make a high impedance 0.5V from a divider, then actual Vref will not be 0.5 V when connected to the ref pin.

the 0,5V of Vref directly come from ADR130BUJZ-REEL7 https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADR130.pdf

I don't find any information on the intern resistance

@DamanZ4 The impedance IC side or circuit side of the VRef pin is irrelevant, only the voltage matters. The main problem is what are all the voltages of all the pins with respect to one of the pins - we usually take the -ve power supply pin, or a pin marked GND if there is one, as our zero reference for all the other pin voltage measurements. Make the measurements, and post them on a schematic in your original question. Your anomolous circuit behaviour cannot be debugged without this.

The reference pin sets the output reference level. This is an instrumentation amplifier with built-in PGA. So ideally the output would be Av((Vin+) - (Vin-))+Vref, where Av is the digitally programmed gain.
Unlike most instrumentation amplifiers, this one uses a flying capacitor topology internally so it has fewer issues with internal nodes saturating (in return you get a bit of subtle weirdness in terms of sensitivity to input resistances and matching of same- see the datasheet), however do heed the equations and limits under "Input Voltage Range".
Like most instrumentation amplifiers, the Vref pin is not high impedance (something like 32kΩ to an internal voltage). For this reason you may wish to drive the Vref pin to something other than 0V.

V– ≤ (Vin+ – Vin–) + Vref ≤ V+ – 1.3

and

V– < Vin+ < V+ and V– < Vin– < V+

There are some additional limits that may apply when using +/- supplies so be sure to read that section.
If you are using +/-5V supplies, for example, you would normally ground the Vref pin. However, for single supply operation you might want to connect Vref to some other voltage within the power supply range. Since the pin (like the Vref pin on most instrumentation amplifiers) is not high impedance you may need a buffer. This is covered in the datasheet.
In the 'Typical Application' shown on the datasheet page 1, for example, the Vref is grounded and a single supply is shown. This has the disadvantage that (since the output cannot be driven below V- = GND) the differential input has to be strictly positive (within a few uV offset) to get any output change. Since the bridge resistors will not be perfect you might also get a dead zone near nominal balance (say zero pressure for a bridge pressure sensor).

Okay, but when i put 500mV in REF and V+ - V- = 500mV, i got 500mV as Vout, and i had to get 1V i think. I am on a 5V to GND supply

What's your gain setting? The datasheet mentions a gain of '0' as a possibility. However it seems to set the output high-Z or something.

I set my gain to 1 by parallele. If I put Vdif of 500mV and Ref to GND I have 500mV as Output but if i have 500mV as Vdif and 500mV as Ref, I have 500mV too

If you can measure that 0.5V voltage right on the chip Vref pin maybe the part is damaged. It does not respond to Vref changes at all? Actually if the pin was open (like unsoldered) you'd get a similar effect.

I get a rising voltage as react, but that return to 500mV. Rising like a DC go to 800mV and back down 500mV. That a new part. I am sure to have 500mV in entrance in REF and 500mV in diff

It sounds a bit like the differential input is floating at the chip pins or something like that. Again, inspect the soldering and your schematic (eg. shutdown input). With the provided information I don't have much else to offer you.
